# EOF error causing termination when handled in using http.Client.Get method and Body.Read() method

Tags: http, go, httprequest, eof

I am using an http client to get a json body, and read it to a byte array like

```
client := new(http.Client)
client.Timeout = time.Second * 10
GetJobJson, err := client.Get(joblocation.String()) //where joblocation is of type *url.Url
if err != nil {
    errorlog.Err.Println("Error getting job from", joblocation.String(), err)
    return false, http.StatusBadRequest, nil
}
buff := make([]byte, GetJobJson.ContentLength)
length, err := GetJobJson.Body.Read(buff) //This returns an EOF error
if err != nil {
    errorlog.Err.Println("Error reading request body of length", length, "vs contentlength", GetJobJson.ContentLength, err)
    return false, http.StatusBadRequest, nil
}
```

In the above code, `GetJobJson.Body` is of type `io.ReadCloser`, which implements `Reader`, having `Read` method, which I am using here as

```
length, err := GetJobJson.Body.Read(buff)
```

But since I am handling error here, it is returning an error which says EOF.

The http endpoint to where I am sending the request is running an apache server, mentioning it here since I am not sure if it matters.

If I am not handling the error, I get the complete json body, which is there in the remote server, and the program continues to work as expected.

What is the best way to handle this? Is the `Read` method that I use, is bad for this situation?

Comment: EOF means you read the entire stream. If you received what you expected, why are you returning that EOF as an error?  (You should also note that it's possible here to be getting chunked responses, which won't have a ContentLength)

Comment: Thank you @JimB. I am not returning EOF. It is returned by the webserver from where I am pulling the content. What is the best way to do it then? Can I ignore only EOF, and handle it?

Comment: @JimB: Could it be that the actual content, and the content length are different? I did an `unsafe.Sizeof(buff)`, which gives a size less than the `ContentLength` size.

Comment: Have you looked at any examples of how to use an io.Reader? Yes, you need to handle EOF.

Comment: unsafe.SizeOf returns the size of the slice structure, which isn't relevant at all. You know what the length and capacity are, because you just allocated it.

Comment: Nice, I will handle EOF then. If you can write the comment as an answer, I will accept it as the solution. Thanks @JimB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handing `io.EOF` is part of the contract of using an `io.Reader`, and it indicates that there's nothing more to read. If you have read what you expected to read, there is no error. If you look at functions like `ioutil.ReadAll`, you'll see that it handles the EOF, and returns no error at the end of the stream.

You may also consider not checking for ContentLength, as it precludes you from handing chunked responses.